# Can the Android YouTube app display annotations?

Tags: youtube

I run the stock YouTube app on my HTC One X phone.

There are a couple of channels I follow who post videos narrated in their local language, but with translations added as annotations on top of the video stream. These are perfectly viewable in my desktop browser but are not displayed in the Android YouTube app.

Is there a setting for this I am missing, or are they just not available?

Comment: Actually, MixerBox 3 did display annotations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Annotations are unfortunately [not supported on Android](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?topic=%C2%AD14354&answer=92710) at this time:

> ## Notes
>
> - Annotations appear on standard YouTube players and embedded players.
> - Annotations **do not** appear on custom YouTube chromeless players.
> - Annotations **do not** appear in video playbacks taking place on mobile, tablet and TV devices.

Someone from Google has evidently [acknowledged this feature request](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/U7Gimd-3ldU/bejKoc_P0gQJ), but I don't believe there's any kind of timeline for its implementation (or official word that it, in fact, *will* be implemented).

Comment: It was technically possible!